# Optaplanner in osgi

Tags: java, osgi, optaplanner

I'm trying to get optaplanner 6.5.0 to work in an osgi environment.
I had to install following bundles to get all dependencies resolved:

```
OptaPlanner coreorg.optaplanner.core                                                            6.5.0.201610181310
XStream Corexstream                                                                             1.4.9
Apache Commons Mathorg.apache.commons.math3                                                     3.4.1
Drools :: Compilerorg.drools.compiler                                                           6.5.0.201610181300
Drools :: Coreorg.drools.core                                                                   6.5.0.201610181300
KIE :: Public APIorg.kie.api                                                                    6.5.0.201610181259
KIE :: Internalorg.kie.internalapi                                                              6.5.0.201610181259
Protocol Buffer Java APIcom.google.protobuf                                                     2.6.0
mvel2org.mvel2                                                                                  2.2.8.Final
Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: javax.injectorg.apache.servicemix.bundles.javax-inject          1.0.0.2
XML Pull Parsing APIorg.xmlpull.v1                                                              1.1.4.redhat-1
Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: xpp3org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xpp3                          1.1.4.c
Apache ServiceMix :: Specs :: Activation API 1.4org.apache.servicemix.specs.activation-api-1.1  2.0.0
Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: jaxb-xjcorg.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-xjc                  2.2.4.1
Apache ServiceMix :: Specs :: JAXB API 2.2org.apache.servicemix.specs.jaxb-api-2.2              2.9.0
Apache ServiceMix :: Specs :: Stax API 1.0org.apache.servicemix.specs.stax-api-1.0              2.9.0
Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: jaxb-implorg.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl                2.2.11.1
Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: reflectionsorg.apache.servicemix.bundles.reflections            0.9.11.1
OptaPlanner persistence commonorg.optaplanner.persistence.common                                6.5.0.201610181310
Sling Metrics :: CQ Fragmentcom.github.digital-wonderland.sling-metrics.cq-metrics-fragment     0.1.0
Guava: Google Core Libraries for Javacom.google.guava                                           18.0.0
```

When testing a simple example, which a got working through a junit test, I get following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Predicate
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.domain.ScanAnnotatedClassesConfig.buildSolutionDescriptor(ScanAnnotatedClassesConfig.java:69)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.buildSolutionDescriptor(SolverConfig.java:278)
    at org.optaplanner.core.config.solver.SolverConfig.buildSolver(SolverConfig.java:229)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolverFactory.buildSolver(AbstractSolverFactory.java:52)
    at com.bekaert.handling.allocation.optimizer.impl.OptimizerTest.before(OptimizerTest.java:55)
    at com.bekaert.handling.allocation.optimizer.impl.TestAllocationOptimizerImpl.activate(TestAllocationOptimizerImpl.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_25]
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.invokeMethod(BaseMethod.java:231)[4:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.access$500(BaseMethod.java:39)[4:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod$Resolved.invoke(BaseMethod.java:624)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.invoke(BaseMethod.java:508)[4:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.ActivateMethod.invoke(ActivateMethod.java:149)[4:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.createImplementationObject(SingleComponentManager.java:315)[4:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.createComponent(SingleComponentManager.java:127)[4:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.getService(SingleComponentManager.java:871)[4:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.getServiceInternal(SingleComponentManager.java:838)[4:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.activateInternal(AbstractComponentManager.java:850)[4:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.enable(AbstractComponentManager.java:419)[4:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.config.ConfigurableComponentHolder.enableComponents(ConfigurableComponentHolder.java:376)[4:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.BundleComponentActivator.initialize(BundleComponentActivator.java:172)[4:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.BundleComponentActivator.<init>(BundleComponentActivator.java:120)[4:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.loadComponents(Activator.java:258)[4:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.access$000(Activator.java:45)[4:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator$ScrExtension.start(Activator.java:185)[4:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
    at org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.createExtension(AbstractExtender.java:259)[4:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
    at org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.modifiedBundle(AbstractExtender.java:232)[4:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleTracker.java:479)[4:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleTracker.java:414)[4:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:232)[4:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleTracker.java:443)[4:org.apache.felix.scr:1.8.2]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeBundleListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:869)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:790)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:515)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:4429)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2100)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:976)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
    at aQute.launcher.Launcher.update(Launcher.java:436)[biz.aQute.launcher-latest.jar:]
    at aQute.launcher.Launcher$1.run(Launcher.java:194)[biz.aQute.launcher-latest.jar:]
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_25]
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_25]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Predicate not found by org.apache.servicemix.bundles.reflections [205]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1556)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:77)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1993)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_25]
    ... 43 more
```

What I noticed is that in the org.apache.servicemix.bundles.reflections bundle the import-package com.google.common.base is optional.
This means it should even be able to work without that package?
I cannot remove the com.google.guava bundle, because it is required for the org.optaplanner.core bundle.

What other things can I try to make this work? Anyone else already managed to get optaplanner working in an osgi environment?

Best regards,
Sigi

Comment: Are you using the osgi features.xml described in the optaplanner docs chapter integration about OSGi?

Answer (score 2):

> What I noticed is that in the org.apache.servicemix.bundles.reflections bundle the import-package com.google.common.base is optional. This means it should even be able to work without that package?

In theory, this is true. However usually when you see `resolution:=optional` for an imported package, what it means is one or more of:

- This was generated by a tool and I didn't really check what it was doing
- This package is only used on some code paths, but not really optional. If you go down any of those code paths it will just explode at runtime
- I just wanted to make my bundle easier to resolve, and didn't understand that the package really was needed.

From the issues you're seeing I'd guess this is a case of the package only being needed on some code paths.

> What other things can I try to make this work? Anyone else already managed to get optaplanner working in an osgi environment?

From the stack trace it looks as though this is failing during configuration, so you may be able to configure around the problem by avoiding the feature that's broken. You could also install a bundle that actually provides `com.google.common.base`, satisfying the optional import.

Another way to go is to completely repackage the library, making sure that you get the OSGi metadata correct. You can also embed other libraries (or parts of libraries) into this repackaged bundle to limit its set of imported packages and/or to work around places where reflective class loading causes problems.

Comment: The OSGi config of optaplanner is defined here: https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-core/pom.xml#L95

Answer (score 0):

I got it working for our case. I wrapped all binaries in one bundle and made some imports optional.

We use BndTools. The .bnd file looks like this:

```
Bundle-Version: 6.5.0.${tstamp}
Service-Component:  \
    *
Export-Package:  \
    org.optaplanner.core.api.*,\
    org.optaplanner.core.impl.*,\
    org.optaplanner.core.config.*;
Include-Resource:  \
    @binaries/annotations-2.0.1.jar,\
    @binaries/antlr-runtime-3.5.jar,\
    @binaries/commons-codec-1.4.jar,\
    @binaries/commons-io-2.1.jar,\
    @binaries/commons-lang3-3.1.jar,\
    @binaries/commons-math3-3.4.1.jar,\
    @binaries/drools-compiler-6.5.0.Final.jar,\
    @binaries/drools-core-6.5.0.Final.jar,\
    @binaries/ecj-4.4.2.jar,\
    @binaries/freemarker-2.3.19.jar,\
    @binaries/guava-13.0.1.jar,\
    @binaries/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar,\
    @binaries/jcommon-1.0.23.jar,\
    @binaries/jfreechart-1.0.19.jar,\
    @binaries/kie-api-6.5.0.Final.jar,\
    @binaries/kie-internal-6.5.0.Final.jar,\
    @binaries/mvel2-2.2.8.Final.jar,\
    @binaries/optaplanner-benchmark-6.5.0.Final.jar,\
    @binaries/optaplanner-core-6.5.0.Final.jar,\
    @binaries/optaplanner-persistence-common-6.5.0.Final.jar,\
    @binaries/optaplanner-persistence-xstream-6.5.0.Final.jar,\
    @binaries/protobuf-java-2.6.0.jar,\
    @binaries/reflections-0.9.10.jar,\
    @binaries/slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar,\
    @binaries/xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar,\
    @binaries/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar,\
    @binaries/xstream-1.4.9.jar

Import-Package:  \
    com.bea.xml.stream;resolution:=optional,\
    com.google.gson;resolution:=optional,\
    com.sun.codemodel;resolution:=optional,\
    com.sun.jdi;resolution:=optional,\
    com.sun.jdi.connect;resolution:=optional,\
    com.sun.jdi.event;resolution:=optional,\
    com.sun.jdi.request;resolution:=optional,\
    com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils;resolution:=optional,\
    com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal;resolution:=optional,\
    com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.objects;resolution:=optional,\
    com.sun.tools.xjc;resolution:=optional,\
    com.sun.tools.xjc.model;resolution:=optional,\
    com.sun.tools.xjc.outline;resolution:=optional,\
    javax.el;resolution:=optional,\
    javax.enterprise.context;resolution:=optional,\
    javax.enterprise.context.spi;resolution:=optional,\
    javax.enterprise.event;resolution:=optional,\
    javax.enterprise.inject;resolution:=optional,\
    javax.enterprise.inject.spi;resolution:=optional,\
    javax.inject;resolution:=optional,\
    javax.enterprise.util;resolution:=optional,\
    javax.servlet.jsp;resolution:=optional,\
    javax.servlet.jsp.el;resolution:=optional,\
    javax.servlet.jsp.tagext;resolution:=optional,\
    net.sf.cglib.proxy;resolution:=optional,\
    nu.xom;resolution:=optional,\
    org.antlr.stringtemplate;resolution:=optional,\
    org.apache.commons.vfs2;resolution:=optional,\
    org.apache.log;resolution:=optional,\
    org.apache.tools.ant;resolution:=optional,\
    org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs;resolution:=optional,\
    org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers;resolution:=optional,\
    org.apache.tools.ant.types;resolution:=optional,\
    org.apache.tools.ant.util;resolution:=optional,\
    org.apache.xml.utils;resolution:=optional,\
    org.apache.xpath;resolution:=optional,\
    org.apache.xpath.objects;resolution:=optional,\
    org.codehaus.janino;resolution:=optional,\
    org.codehaus.janino.util;resolution:=optional,\
    org.codehaus.janino.util.enumerator;resolution:=optional,\
    org.codehaus.janino.util.resource;resolution:=optional,\
    org.codehaus.jettison;resolution:=optional,\
    org.codehaus.jettison.mapped;resolution:=optional,\
    org.dom4j;resolution:=optional,\
    org.dom4j.io;resolution:=optional,\
    org.dom4j.tree;resolution:=optional,\
    org.eclipse.jdt.core.index;resolution:=optional,\
    org.eclipse.jdt.core.util;resolution:=optional,\
    org.jaxen;resolution:=optional,\
    org.jaxen.dom;resolution:=optional,\
    org.jaxen.dom4j;resolution:=optional,\
    org.jaxen.jdom;resolution:=optional,\
    org.jdom;resolution:=optional,\
    org.jdom.input;resolution:=optional,\
    org.jdom.output;resolution:=optional,\
    org.jdom2;resolution:=optional,\
    org.jdom2.input;resolution:=optional,\
    org.joda.time;resolution:=optional,\
    org.joda.time.format;resolution:=optional,\
    org.kxml2.io;resolution:=optional,\
    org.mozilla.javascript;resolution:=optional,\
    org.python.core;resolution:=optional,\
    org.python.util;resolution:=optional,\
    org.slf4j.impl;resolution:=optional,\
    org.w3c.dom.traversal;resolution:=optional,\
    org.zeroturnaround.javarebel;resolution:=optional,\
    sun.misc;resolution:=optional,\
    *
```

Maybe this is not the best way of doing this. But we can use this bundle in our osgi environment and our vehicle routing problem is being solved as expected.

Comment: This is the right approach, but having that number of optional imports is not normally advisable. You should possibly look at the `-conditionalpackage` instruction to package up only the things that are needed, and exclude the Imports that you don't need. That way you'll get something that behaves more consistently.